# JSON Get List of attributes values

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have the following JSON, and I want to take a list of IDs with its values

For example in LINQ something like this: **result.Select(x=>x.id)**

I tried this:

```
 var inner = outer["pictures"].Value<JArray>().ToList();
```

I have a list there but with all attributes but I am not able to select just IDs since it is an anonymous list.

```
    outer
{{
  "id": "669654603",
  "pictures": [
    {
      "id": "659745-MLA25600661898_052017",
      "url": "http://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/659745-MLA25600661898_052017-O.jpg",
      "secure_url": "https://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/659745-MLA25600661898_052017-O.jpg",
      "size": "500x365",
      "max_size": "625x457",
      "quality": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "908422-MLA25658267858_062017",
      "url": "http://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/908422-MLA25658267858_062017-O.jpg",
      "secure_url": "https://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/908422-MLA25658267858_062017-O.jpg",
      "size": "47x47",
      "max_size": "47x47",
      "quality": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "794138-MLA25658267889_062017",
      "url": "http://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/794138-MLA25658267889_062017-O.jpg",
      "secure_url": "https://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/794138-MLA25658267889_062017-O.jpg",
      "size": "40x40",
      "max_size": "40x40",
      "quality": ""
    }
  ]


}}
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON document

Comment: @SirRufo Sorry I had a big JSON and I cut it for this example, seems that I did it wrong.

Comment: you can also visit http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Newtonsoft JSON you can do it like this:

```
var values = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["pictures"].Select(p => p["id"].Value<string>()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be valid your json should not contain double curly brackets:

```
{
  "id": "669654603",
  "pictures": [ ... ]
}
```

You can parse it without additional classes:

```
var ids = JObject.Parse(json)["pictures"].Select(p => (string)p["id"]);
```

Output:

```
[
  "659745-MLA25600661898_052017",
  "908422-MLA25658267858_062017",
  "794138-MLA25658267889_062017"
]
```

---

Or you can create several classes to hold your json data:

```
public class Container
{
    public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // you can add other properties here
}
```

And use strongly-typed parsing:

```
var ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json).Pictures.Select(p => p.Id);
```